# Is it possible to do Search a users tweets through Streaming API?

Tags: php, twitter

I am doing a project that takes in a high volume of tweets. 
From the current users that are returned tweeting for example "frog", I want to use STREAMING API to search user X's profile for more occurrences of the word "frog" 
In the search API this was simple, I would get the user id of the current tweets and then run code like this:

$json = file_get_contents('http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?user_id='.$user_id,0,null,null);

and then I would search the user timeline for occurrences of that word. How do I do this in the Streaming API. 
I'm using the Phirhose library for PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Short. You can't.

The Streaming API is a live feed and doesn't allow you to "search". You'll need to use either the Search API or the REST API for this purpose in conjunction with the Streaming API

Twitter Streaming API documentation can be found here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-api

Regards